# Show content by using tags

Tags: php, customization, tags, content

I want to show some content based by tags of a user, that is how i would like to do it, but it did not work:

```
$args = array($arg1,$arg2,$argn);

function show_tag_content($path){
  $post = get_page_by_path($path);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
  echo $content;
}

for ($i = 0; i<count($args);$i++){
show_tag_content('blog/tag/' . $args[$i]);
}
```

tried the function with a hard string without using blog and more than one page content, e. g.:

```
show_tag_content('login');
show_tag_content('news');
```

works perfect, tried it that way:

```
show_tag_content('blog/tag/example');
```

nothing

Need some help here at this point

Comment: Any error? try `var_dump($post);` after using `get_page_by_path($path);` to see what is the function returning.

Answer (score 0):

in case someone else in searching for this, I used a WP Query with the statement tag:

```
$args = array (myargs1,....,myargsn);
for ($i=0; $i<count($args);$i++){
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => $args[$i] ) );
```

...and so on with if have_posts() and a while loop, you can find the whole syntax on wordpress.org, only thing i did working with a for-loop to run run my array